# model high frequency bitcoin volatility

Tags: volatility, garch, high-frequency, bitcoin

I am trying to model volatility of 1-minute returns of BTC, but it seems to me that the data do not behave traditionally. I tried fitting GARCH, eGARCH with ARMA (1,1) or (2,0), but I am not confident that either actually fit well. The data exhibit often zero-return and when I compare it to garch-simulated data ours exhibit clearly microstructure noise and behave differently [image] and the returns are rather low in general. The period with highest return in the sample [image]

The ACF and PACF seems little unusual[[image: sample afc and pacf]]

After fitting a garch, the squared residuals of the fit look the same as in the original series -> no arch effect seems to be modelled.

**So my question is whether GARCH approach is even valid in this case?**  The output of one of garch models on full sample (73 k observations) is as follows (smaller sample has insignificant coefficients):

```
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics    
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : eGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(2,0,0)
Distribution    : std 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error     t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.000000    0.000000 -1.9930e-03  0.99841
ar1     0.050520    0.003378  1.4956e+01  0.00000
ar2    -0.038044    0.003214 -1.1837e+01  0.00000
omega  -0.419248    0.000746 -5.6196e+02  0.00000
alpha1  0.048651    0.003691  1.3182e+01  0.00000
beta1   0.975087    0.000058  1.6759e+04  0.00000
gamma1  0.574946    0.003953  1.4545e+02  0.00000
shape   2.508783    0.005877  4.2687e+02  0.00000

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.000000    0.000007  -0.000016 0.999987
ar1     0.050520    0.008469   5.965290 0.000000
ar2    -0.038044    0.004451  -8.547390 0.000000
omega  -0.419248    0.034581 -12.123488 0.000000
alpha1  0.048651    0.012999   3.742817 0.000182
beta1   0.975087    0.002306 422.906412 0.000000
gamma1  0.574946    0.016985  33.849762 0.000000
shape   2.508783    0.018145 138.261378 0.000000

LogLikelihood : 692467.3 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------

Akaike       -14.156
Bayes        -14.155
Shibata      -14.156
Hannan-Quinn -14.156

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                   0.008437  0.9268
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]  0.033719  1.0000
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9]  0.037504  1.0000
d.o.f=2
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                  1.606e-05  0.9968
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5] 4.819e-05  1.0000
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9] 8.032e-05  1.0000
d.o.f=2

Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
            Statistic Shape Scale P-Value
ARCH Lag[3] 1.606e-05 0.500 2.000  0.9968
ARCH Lag[5] 3.855e-05 1.440 1.667  1.0000
ARCH Lag[7] 5.737e-05 2.315 1.543  1.0000

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  2124.693
Individual Statistics:             
mu      11.44
ar1    161.81
ar2     43.00
omega  559.78
alpha1  44.98
beta1  869.78
gamma1 832.78
shape  440.51

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Joint Statistic:         1.89 2.11 2.59
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                     t-value   prob sig
Sign Bias          1.0466011 0.2953    
Negative Sign Bias 0.0003836 0.9997    
Positive Sign Bias 0.6256527 0.5315    
Joint Effect       1.3371473 0.7203    


Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     85598            0
2    30    101805            0
3    40    112434            0
4    50    120823            0


Elapsed time : 21.09595 2
```

Thank you very much for all suggestions how to continue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for stock data, classical GARCH models are designed to model daily volatilities, but not the intraday ones, because, for instance, they do not capture diurnal patterns. So, I would say that models you are estimating are not valid for the 1-minutes returns. And of course, the presence of the microstructure noise makes them even less valid.

As a possible solution, you might want to look at the Multiplicative Component GARCH for intraday returns. Alternatively, you can calculate daily realized volatilities based on high-frequency data you have and employ, for instance, the realized GARCH to model daily volatility dynamics.

Comment: Thanks, I have been studying further about microstructure noise and realised volatility! Thanks a lot for nudging in the right direction